# Can't run the google-api-java-client samples in eclipse

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to run the YouTube [JSON-C Sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/youtube-jsonc-sample/instructions.html?r=default) in eclipse. I have followed the instructions in the link and I managed to run it in the command line using mvn -q exec:java, but when I import the project to eclipse (I use eclipse indigo), it says that "The import com.google.api.client.googleapis cannot be resolved", and gives me compiler errors in every line that is related to the api. Is there some other configuration that needs to be done? Specifically adding google-api-java-client-1.5.0-beta jars to the build path?

Comment: Have you installed Eclipse M2 plugin? Once you have it installed, then you just need to import the project as an existing Maven project in eclipse.

Comment: Yes I did. The maven plugin is definitely installed. And so is the mercurial plugin (if that matters).

Comment: Try to update the Maven dependencies and Project Configuration and make sure the correct JAR's are added to the build path.

Comment: Wait a minute.. I managed to compile and run the project from the terminal, so it must be related solely to the plugin's configurations, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally solved the problem. What did the work for me was to execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the project folder in terminal...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you are pulling out all the dependencies in `pom.xml` from the repository:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-beta</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-beta</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Check the `settings.xml` file in the Maven installation directory if it is pointing to a global repository or if you have hosted your own Nexus/Sonatype repository then make sure that your `settings.xml` points to that and also you must have the above two jars in your repository.

Or if you just want to get the project up and running, then instead of importing as a Maven project, just import it as a normal Java project and manually add the two libraries to the project's classpath. That should at the least get you started with the project without worrying about the Maven stuff.

Comment: I did try to add the specific libraries to the build path. The compile errors disappeared but I got a runtime error like:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
 at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:43)
 at com.google.api.client.sample.youtube.YouTubeClient.<init>(YouTubeClient.java:34)
 at com.google.api.client.sample.youtube.YouTubeSample.run(YouTubeSample.java:27)
 at com.google.api.client.sample.youtube.YouTubeSample.main(YouTubeSample.java:34). BTW how do I find the Maven installation directory?